# Loop through multiple arrays with objects inside them in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

I'm currently struggling to use a forEach method to loop over an array with multiple objects in it. I might be making a silly mistake but im not sure where im going wrong with this

I have an object with some arrays like this...

assistants array:

```
var assistants =
[  
   {    
         "countryCode":"US",
         "cityName":"San Diego",
         "geographicRegionCode":"CA"
   },
   {
         "countryCode":"AD",
         "cityName":"a",
         "geographicRegionCode":null
   }
]
```

function im using to loop through and return a value...

```
     function validateAssistants () {
          angular.forEach(assistants, function(a) {
            if(a.countryCode === "US") {
              return true;
            }
          });
      }
```

When i am going to debug...it keeps on saying that a is not defined. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Mostly because there is a typo here `"countryCode": "AD"`.No comma

Answer (score 1):

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) works like `[1,2,3].forEach(callback)`, but the best best way, in my opinion is using [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) to find if some element match, like `assistants.some(o=>o.countryCode == "US")`.

```js
var assistants =
[  
   {    
         "countryCode":"US",
         "cityName":"San Diego",
         "geographicRegionCode":"CA"
   },
   {
         "countryCode":"AD",
         "cityName":"a",
         "geographicRegionCode":null
   }
]


assistants.forEach((o)=>{

if(o.countryCode === "US") {
         console.log(true);
        }

})

console.log(assistants.some(o=>o.countryCode == "US"))//<-- best
```

`forEach()` iterates all elements, if you find the match at 0 position continues iterating till the end without need, `some` or `for` (with break), stops when find the match.